# Generating rules for section, subsection and subsubsection

Tags: formatting, rules, small-caps, section-titles

I would like to have a template rule at the beginning of my document, that will make my sections, subsection and subsubsections to look as below:

A. FIRST SECTION FONT CENTURY SMALL CAPS BOLD Grey Background across the whole page

**1. This is subsection font Century bold**

*This is subsubsection font Century Italic Underline*

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Regarding your question, it would be helpful to know, which document class you want to use.

Comment: I started to use \documentclass[10pt]{article} and was planning to modify by rewritting some rules. Specifically right now it has: 
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}% name
  {1}% level
  {0mm}% indent
  {1pt}% beforeskip
  {1pt}% afterskip
  {\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter

Was hopping to change those to meet my needs.

Comment: you could have a look into https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec and then post your specific questions.

Comment: Admittedly \@startsection is a pain to modify.  It is easier to copy and modify \chapter instead,  See https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en.